# MKT capacitor with ohm value on case markings

Tags: capacitor, markings

This MKT capacitor has an ohm value written on the case. Is it the equivalent series resistance (ESR?)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to provide an alternative answer, as to me it makes no sense to have a complex impedance of 0.25J + 200 Ohms printed on a capacitor-looking device, when I know that components that are marked similarly do exist and these have both a capacitor and a resistor combined in one package.

So, most likely that component is a RC snubber component, a device with a capacitor and a resistor in series.

The marking seems to indicate 0.25 units of capacitance, with the units of "uF" for microfarads not printed like on other snubber capacitors. That would indicate 250nF of capacitance.

The J is for 5% capacitor tolerance, many other snubber capacitors have K there for 10% capacitor tolerance.

The 200 ohms is the value for the series resistor component.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1

Comment: As a similar example [this](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_F3089_P409_X2_275.pdf) part.